# What's the best place to post suggestions for Apple to read?

Tags: software-recommendation

As mentioned in [this post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/28081/is-it-possible-to-suppress-hidden-calendars-in-ios-5s-notification-view), I'm wondering where I should put UI suggestions for apple.

Comment: http://www.apple.com/feedback/macosx.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I always prefer this chain:

1. Speak with an Apple Employee - ask them who exactly is best to hear the specific feedback. Who better to know what the best channel for your idea / feedback than the people trained to interact with the public. Just be aware that not all employees will be in a position to take your feedback, but they might be taking mental notes to send it up even if they don't let on or promise you they will follow up on your feedback.
2. If it's really a bug in the hardware/software, you can file a bug at http://bugreport.apple.com
3. There's always http://apple.com/feedback

Answer (score 1):

If you have a developer account, you can raise it on radar:

http://developer.apple.com/bugreporter/